# Why does my isp advice against using an IP as MX?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I'm wondering why I've heard a couple of times that it's bad to enter an IP directly as MX record. Most ISP's advise us to create an A record with the mailserver IP and use that A-record as MX record.

I've entered an IP as MX before and it worked most of the time but there were cases that it didn't work. Can't seem to find why.

Is there a reasonable explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various RFCs relating to DNS and mail exchange specify that an MX record consists of a preference value and an domain name with an address (`A`) record.

See [RFC 2181, section 10.3:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.3)

```
10.3. MX and NS records

The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part of
the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias.  Not only is
the specification clear on this point, but using an alias in either
of these positions neither works as well as might be hoped, nor well
fulfills the ambition that may have led to this approach.  This
domain name must have as its value one or more address records.
Currently those will be A records, however in the future other record
types giving addressing information may be acceptable.  It can also
have other RRs, but never a CNAME RR.
```

Comment: AAAA is the other common RR in use.

Comment: True, but RFC 2181 predates IPv6 by about 1.5 years, hence AAAA was not specifically mentioned. It is an "other record
types giving addressing information" as mentioned in the RFC, so it can be used as an MX record's host part.

Answer (score 1):

the reson is usually given by the receiving MTA. normally, IP based mx records get blocked, because spammers use them all the time